# What can I do to break up long body text for a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm working with a dictionary database that has translations of a term that look something like this in the original excel files:

> water - [uo-tar] s. 1. Agua (H2O). Rain-water, agua llovediza.
>   Fresh-water, agua dulce. Spring-water, agua de fuente o de manantial.
>   Holy water, agua bendita. Well-water o pump-water, agua de pozo.
>   Running water, agua viva o corriente. Salt water, agua del mar, agua
>   salada. 2. Cualquier extensión determinada de agua; v. gr. un lago, un
>   río, un mar. To go by water, ir por mar. High water, marea alta. Low
>   water, marea baja. 3. Serosidad o humor de los animales;
>   transpiración, lágrimas u orina.

The main word "water", the pronunciation "[uo-tar]" and the translation "s. 1. Agua (H2O)..." are separate fields. When importing the translation into drupal 7 using feeds I would like to be able to adjust the format of all the translation to something like this:

> water - [uo-tar] s.
>
> 1. Agua (H2O). Rain-water, agua llovediza.
>      Fresh-water, agua dulce. Spring-water, agua de fuente o de manantial.
>      Holy water, agua bendita. Well-water o pump-water, agua de pozo.
>      Running water, agua viva o corriente. Salt water, agua del mar, agua
>      salada.
> 2. Cualquier extensión determinada de agua; v. gr. un
>      lago, un río, un mar. To go by water, ir por mar. High water, marea
>      alta. Low water, marea baja.
> 3. Serosidad o humor de los
>      animales; transpiración, lágrimas u orina.

I don't know if any one could give me some advice on different ways of doing this or if its even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Are each sense of the word separate fields in the source database?

Comment: as @MarkTrapp said, if you access source database and each definition are in referent row, you can do this migration completely, otherwise you should use regx to separate definitions with uncertainty

Comment: No, unfortunately all definitions are meshed together in a big paragraph. They have some html elements (<em>, <strong>) but the definitions are not broken up.

Comment: Did you see if [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) has options that could fit your needs ? If not, you may be able to write a custom plugin for it. It's very simple and it can make wonders.

Comment: Thank You! I managed to get feeds tamper to work perfectly with their Regex plugin. It actually comes quite in handy.